# Has "mother" become politically incorrect?

Tags: nouns, political-correctness

Has *mother* become politically incorrect? The word *mom* now seems to have replaced *mother* throughout popular news articles.

Is there some reason besides political correctness, which until now has always seemed to have been connected to racism, no matter how tenuous the connection, or have I missed something?

Comment: I only call her "mother" when I simultaneously roll my eyes at something she said, as in "Oh, mother!"

Comment: I think OP has got it the wrong way around. It's not that *mother* has "fallen out of favour". It's that the popular press have reached the point where they no longer feel that *mom* (*mum* in the UK) sounds excessively "downmarket" or childish.

Comment: "... throughout popular news articles." Care to cite references? The **whole question** stands on this premise, so it can crumble as a NARQ unless the claim is substantiated.

Comment: I do recall reading an article in the _Times_ (long ago) about family life which managed to avoid using the words _mother_ and _father_ throughout (they were _female parent_ and _male parent_) so there may be something in the notion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ...even though it *does* sound silly! But then, the press...

Answer (score 10):

Here are the usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (number of instances per million words, by context):

```
           SPOKEN  FICTION  MAGAZINE NEWSPAPER ACADEMIC 

mother      281      939      287       253      134 
mom         125      204      102        59        6
```

And now the same stats sorted by year:

```
         1990–1994 1995–1999 2000–2004 2005–2009 2010–2012

mother      361       413       382       359       353 
mom          58        94       103       122       139
```

While we're at it, for a more complete picture, let's also check the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/):

[image]

<sup>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words)</sup>

What we can see is that *mom* has indeed been gaining ground, but it's nowhere near surpassing *mother*.

And if you think that *mom* is more politically correct than *mother*, you must be forgetting ["your mom" jokes](http://xkcd.com/366/).

Comment: Those are "Yo mama" jokes, tyvm.

Comment: @Robusto [Joe Momma](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Joe%20Mamma)?

Comment: So's yer mam on toast.

Comment: Very well, I'll try again with no attempt at humour. @Robusto: Not all "your mom" jokes are "yo mama" jokes. The latter are things like ["Yo mama so old, her last name is Osaurus."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzelrlH_pjQ) The former include ["That's what your mother said last night!"](http://snltranscripts.jt.org/08/08vjeopardy.phtml)" and ["Good job throwing the kid off the fence, genius." "Your mom's a genius!"](http://www.avclub.com/articles/the-inconveniencing,84649/)". So it is not valid to correct RegDwighт's mention of "'your mom' jokes" to "yo mama" jokes.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Full disclosure — I'm just having fun with my old buddy on EL&U. He didn't take it seriously, and neither did the rest of the regulars. Welcome to EL&U. When you can tell I'm joking, you might get to be a regular too.

Comment: @Robusto the earliest I know was a "your mother" joke: "Villain, what hast thou done?" "That which thou canst not undo." "Thou hast undone our mother." "Villain, I have done thy mother." ("Titus Andronicus")

Answer (score 2):

*Mother* is not politically incorrect. *Mom* is just a shorter, friendlier term for the same person.

Consider the organization [Mothers Against Drunk Driving](http://www.madd.org/). They're political, but certainly not incorrect.

Comment: A kinder, gentler term.